# Genericizing Constructors in Scala

Tags: scala, generics, traits

I've been doing some exercises in Scala. I thought I might try to derive a method of creating incompatible value types that cannot be accidentally assigned to each other, using the newly added `AnyVal` trait.

The best I could come up with was something like this:

```
object Measurements {
  trait ValueType[T] extends Any {
    def value: T
  }

  trait Measurement[A <: ValueType[Double]] extends Any {
    def modify(fn: (Double, A) => Double, value: A): A
    def +(mod: A) = modify((x: Double, y: A) => x + y.value, mod)
    def -(mod: A) = modify((x: Double, y: A) => x - y.value, mod)
    def *(mod: A) = modify((x: Double, y: A) => x * y.value, mod)
    def /(mod: A) = modify((x: Double, y: A) => x / y.value, mod)
  }

  case class Frequency(value: Double) extends AnyVal 
      with ValueType[Double] 
      with Measurement[Frequency] 
  {
    def modify(fn: (Double, Frequency) => Double, mod: Frequency) 
      = Frequency(fn(value, mod))
  }

  case class Amplitude(value: Double) extends AnyVal 
      with ValueType[Double] 
      with Measurement[Amplitude] 
  {
    def modify(fn: (Double, Amplitude) => Double, mod: Amplitude) 
      = Amplitude(fn(value, mod))
  }

  case class Wavelength(value: Double) extends AnyVal 
      with ValueType[Double] 
      with Measurement[Wavelength] 
  {
    def modify(fn: (Double, Wavelength) => Double, mod: Wavelength) 
      = Wavelength(fn(value, mod))
  }
}
import Measurements._
Frequency(150) + Frequency(10) // ==> Frequency(160)
Amplitude(23.2) * Amplitude(2) // ==> Amplitude(46.4)
Amplitude(50) + Frequency(50)  // ==> Compile-time Type Error
```

Unfortunately it requires that I define the `modify` function uniquely for each instance, because it's impossible to define something like `A(value)` with a generic type `A`. There doesn't seem to be a way to define constructor constraints. Otherwise I might be able to define something common on the trait, like:

```
def modify(fn: (Double, A) => Double, mod: A) = A(fn(value, mod))
```

I've tried calling `apply(Double)` on `A`, but it's not accessible from a generic variable. I also tried to see if I could work up a factory of some kind to at least simplify things, but wasn't able to come up with anything more graceful than what I'm doing now. I run into the same problem with C# all the time.

Is there some way to factor out that code that relies on a common constructor type for different (but related) classes?

Comment: Your program could be improved upon without reflection by employing type classes. Check out [Daniel Westheide's article on the subject from his outstanding _Neophyte's Guide to Scala_](http://danielwestheide.com/blog/2013/02/06/the-neophytes-guide-to-scala-part-12-type-classes.html). And—while it's probably irrelevant at this point—check out [Squants](http://squants.com), a “framework of data types and a domain specific language (DSL) for representing Quantities, their Units of Measure, and their Dimensional relationships.”

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't think that this is possible without resorting to runtime reflection (or maybe macros). There are basically three problem, of which you already pointed out two:

- It is not possible for a trait to declare a mandatory constructor signature.
- It is not possible to call methods such as `apply` on `A` because it is a type variable and not a class or object.
- Since value classes can (currently) only extend [*universal traits*](http://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/core/value-classes.html), but not abstract classes, it is not possible to use `TypeTags` in order to get the class that belongs to the type that `A` is instantiated with when `Measurement` is extended.

The best I could come up with is the following approach. Note, that it uses reflection and that exceptions can be thrown at runtime if the concrete instance of `Measurement` does not declare an appropriate constructor.

```
// ... as above ...

trait Measurement[A <: ValueType[Double]] extends Any { self: A =>
  def modify(fn: (Double, A) => Double, mod: A): A =
    this.getClass
        .getConstructor(this.getClass)
        .newInstance(fn(value, mod): java.lang.Double)

  // ... as above ...
}

case class Frequency(value: Double)
    extends AnyVal 
       with ValueType[Double] 
       with Measurement[Frequency]

// ... etc ...

Frequency(150) + Frequency(10) // ==> Frequency(160)
Amplitude(23.2) * Amplitude(2) // ==> Amplitude(46.4)
Amplitude(50) + Frequency(50)  // ==> Compile-time Type Error
```

The self-type annotation `self: A` ensures that the `value` field declared by `ValueType` is accessible from inside trait `Measurement`.

Comment: I kinda feared that was the case (it took two days for anybody to even attempt an answer). The reflection solution does work, but generally at the cost of performance and safety, which is a shame. Still, good to have as a reference. +1 w/accept